# Trying to make a onmouseover javascript drop down menu

Tags: javascript

[Effect I want](http://www.table2css.com/articles/how-create-horizontal-css-drop-down-menu-search-engine-friendly)  . Basically I want to popup a simple menu when the user mouseovers a link .
I tried several ready made scripts , but had trouble integrating them with my site. SO decided to built my own.
here is what I am trying to do:

```
   <li onmouseover=showlist1() onmouseout=hidelist1() ><a class="navigation"  href="show_delhi_items.php">Menu heading</a></li>

 function showlist1() //onmouseover
  {
     
      document.getElementById('list1').style.visibility='visible' ;
     
  }
  function hidelist1() //onmouseout
  {
      if (menu elements don't have focus)
      {
      document.getElementById('list1').style.visibility='hidden' ;
      }
  }
```

now in this how do I implement the 'menu elements don't have focus' part ? I know its not possible to know which elemtn has focus. so I need an alternative. Basically the problem is that as soon as the mouse moves outside the main link(the link that popups the hidden menu), the menu hides. what i want is for the menu to remain visible if it gets focus. but currently it gets hidden as soon as the mouse outside our main link

hope I was clear enough.

Comment: You don't need javascript for these types of menus, be smart and build it using css :hover instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the menu overlap the list item that has the onmouseover menu. Then only close the menu if the mouse is outside both the list item and the menu. You will have to use:

```
position: absolute;
top: some-y-value;
left: some-x-value;
```

Comment: >close the menu if the mouse is outside both the list item and the menu. How do I detect this ? i can find find if the mouse is outside the list item , but how do I find if the mouse is outside the menu aswell ?

Comment: You can close the menu when the cursor goes over the body of the document instead of when it leaves the list item or menu. You'll have to use "event.cancelBubble = true;" if it's closing when you don't want it to.

Comment: thanks, this may work. after I figure out how to find the event which fires when the cursor goes over the body of the document

Answer (score 1):

Hmm now I made that comment i better back it up with an actual way of doing it :)

[Go here and read all about suckerfish dropdowns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/)

[Go here to see an example implementation](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/example/)